# Error Creating json project configuration file for Implementing GCM Client on Android

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging, app-id, package-name

I am trying to get gcm working in my app.
It is my job to update the app from the Eclipse build to the Android studio build.
In the Android Studio build it no longer works to just plug in gcm.jar, so
I am following this documentation: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client to get my app running with gcm.

In order to do that I need to create a json configuration file. 
To make that file I must give google's configuration file creator my appId and my packageName.

I have entered them into google's form, and upon entry I get the error: "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again."

This error message is very vague.

I have attempted again in internet explorer with the same result.

Is there possibly an error with my appId and packageName? How would I find out?
It is possible that this service is just down and I should wait until tomorrow, but I want to exhaust all my options first.

My appId and packageName are both "myCompanyName.android"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out a moment ago that creating a client ID for the app in developer console project removes this error and allows the config file to be created...

```
Developer console projects
APIs & auth
Credentials
Create new client ID:
  Installed application
  Android
  Enter package name
  Enter SHA1 for RELEASE OR DEBUG (which ever one you want it to work with)
  Make deep linking choice
  Create
```

Then went back to the page and it works. Could be other stuff in the console that you need to do but idk as I already have other stuff set up.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the form just won't accept periods in the application name.  I am unsure why periods are acceptable in the application name within my build then.

Anyway, I will leave this question up here in case someone else runs into this problem because the error message is soooooooo vague.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem? Did you change the application name? What fixed your problem?

Comment: I got this error when I started my app name with a number eg, '4Example'. Changed it to 'FourExample' and it worked fine.

Comment: Getting this error when trying to get config file with Google Sign-in, app invites, and for prefilled app invites sample so it does not have to be a formatting problem.
Error for me is returned as: 500 internal server error
"status":500,"message":"The user is not allowed access: Support email may only be changed to the current user"

Comment: Let us know how you fixed it if you manage to so others can benefit from our knowledges pls, I feel like this particular Android stuff is not well documented,

Comment: Just posted an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue while logging to google using multiple accounts.

[image]

Just login using single account and problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

And for me the solution was as simple as:

1. logout from Firebase
2. log in to Firebase