# Error while trying to upload p12 file to GCM for ios

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, google-developer-tools

I have been trying to enable GCM for ios client using the below link

```
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client
```

but I have been facing an issue as soon as I try to upload a .p12 file on the developer portal while trying to get a configuration file 
 below is the snapshot of the error I encountered.

[image]

if any one has encountered the same, please let me know how you solved it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO-30604318](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604318/error-creating-json-project-configuration-file-for-implementing-gcm-client-on-an)

Comment: @gerardnimo no its not

Answer (score 0):

you have already more than four project in google console developer.