# GCM - Getting Error message "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again." when creating new project

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We are trying to get API Key and Sender ID using Google Developer Console  https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

We enter the App Name and Android Package Name using correct format.  We get the error message "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again."

A couple of weeks ago we could use this process and had no issues.

When I click the link and go to the Developer Console - the project was created.  And we can use the console to get the API Key and Sender ID.  The problem is we need to have the SHA-1 to create the API key, and that's more difficult process.

Anyone else having this issue?  Is this a temporary issue with Google GCM, or do we need to go through the Developer Console t create the API key?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604318/error-creating-json-project-configuration-file-for-implementing-gcm-client-on-an

Comment: Account with which you are looged in to browser would be the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue while logging to google using multiple accounts.

[image]

**log in to single google** account and try.